# Website where people contribute descriptions of NPCs, items, cities and so on

Tags: product-identification, online-resources

I'm looking for a specific website that I saw a year ago or so. I just cannot remember the name but I'm sure it is reasonably well known here.

It is a website that hosts stories and descriptions of several different things related to RPG. For example I remember having seen detailed descriptions of various items, characters and places (houses, taverns, villages, towns), sometimes even illustrated. For every contribution you can fill several fields, such as the RPG-system and the era (past, futuristic, etc.) it is intended for or if it is a magical item or not.

Everybody can contribute to the website and I think there are some contests also from time to time and badges you can win for extraordinary contributions.

I think it is in English but I'm not a 100% sure (*might* have been German).

It seemed like a great resource to me. I'm sure I would immediately recognize it again if it hasn't changed its design much or maybe I would even remember its name if mentioned.

I further remember that contributions to the website were mostly not system-specific. So, rather than detailing hard rules about, say, a broadswoard it provided much more a history or interesting tale about a specific item, person or place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like [Strolen's Citadel](https://strolen.com/). It's community-driven, strongly categorised and searchable in the ways you describe, and does have community contests.

Comment: Yes, that's it! That name rings a bell! Thanks, I knew I would find help here :) ... you were too fast though, you still need to wait 3 minutes for me to accept the answer

Comment: +1 just because Strolen is awesome, and every GM should know about it =)